# React es6 es2015 modal popup

Tags: modal-dialog, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm very new to React and ES6. I'm building a small application using React and I'm following ES6 standard. Now I need to open a modal window on a button click.

I tried react-bootstrap modal and skylight. But did not find much luck.

Can anyone suggest the best way of opening/closing modal along with a callback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

I've put together an example to illustrate how you might go about this, making use of the parent/child relationship and passing down a callback.

The scenario is basically:

- There is a parent `<App />` component
- It can show a `<Modal />` component
- `<App />` controls whether the `<Modal />` is open or not
- `<App />` passes its child, `<Modal />`, a callback to "closeModal"

See this JSBin example for the full solution in action: http://jsbin.com/cokola/edit?js,output

And a visual summary:

[image: React Modal using Callbacks]

`<Modal />` is just a "dumb" component. It does not "control" whether it is open or not. This is up to the parent `<App />`. The parent informs it of how to close itself via passing down a callback `this.props.closeModal`

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { closeModal } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="jumbotron" style={{position: 'absolute', width: '100%', top: 0, height: 500}}>
        <h1>Some Modal</h1>
        <button 
          className="btn btn-md btn-primary" 
          onClick={closeModal}
          >Close Modal</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`<App />` is aware of the open/closed state and controls its child, `<Modal />`

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalOpen: false
    };
  }

  _openModal() {
    this.setState({modalOpen: true});
  }

  _closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalOpen: false});
  }

  render() {
    const { modalOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          className="btn btn-md btn-primary" 
          onClick={this._openModal.bind(this)}
          >Open Modal</button>

        {/* Only show Modal when "this.state.modalOpen === true" */}
        {modalOpen 
          ? <Modal closeModal={this._closeModal.bind(this)} />
          : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```