# How to Create a custom modal in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

we need to create a modal dialog with overlay background in Reactjs as React components.when the user click on the overlay ,the modal should be closed.we need to create the modal in a way that it is reusable React component. somebody plz guide me home i can implement this

Comment: Take a look at react-bootstrap - it implements the functionality you are searching for.

Comment: do you want this modal to contain always the same html (jsx) structure or specific html for each case?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend strolling through react-modal's source https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal for "how to" implement your own.

I've gone down this route of implementing custom modals from scratch a few times myself now, and I must recommend simply pulling in react-modal rather than attempting to reinvent that same wheel [I've since replaced homegrown implementations w/ react-modal]. I've experimented w/ a few different React modal packages and react-modal is fully customizable, battle tested, and has a great API.

I have answered nearly identical questions here: [How to: ES6 React Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454909/2644281) and here: [React conditional render pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34348165/2644281) with some more thoughts/examples/links.

Answer (score 0):

Just for alternative route you could use the new `<dialog>` element, the browser support is rather low (http://caniuse.com/#search=dialog), but with polyfill this could be fixed. But this gives quite easy and extendable way to create dialogs, see demo [here](http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/).

Comment: This is the first I've heard of a native dialog element. Wow, that is going to be amazing once browser support catches up! I'm going to have to keep an eye on this one.